# How to use pytest-mock while debugging

Tags: python, unit-testing, parsing, pytest-mock

I think I am missing something fundamental here and could really use some help.

I am writing a unittest using the pytest-mock mocker feature, like this

```
def my_unittest(mocker):
    m = mocker.spy(my_module, 'my_func')  
    
    calling_a_func_which_calls_my_func()
    
    # Check it was called
    assert m.call_count == 1
```

Now, how do I call my_unittest while debugging? I.e. how do I get an instance of the mocker object, which I can then pass to the function? Something like

```
mocker = pytest_mock.mocker()

my_unittest(mocker)
```

Again, please enlighten me. It really feels like I am missing something here. Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, usually you name the function, in your case `my_unittest`->`test_what_you_are_testing` and then you run `pytest "folder with file with your test.py file"` and it will run the test (runs everything with test in the name)

Comment: Yes, I know that and that's how I normally run my tests, when they are ready. 

I am asking if there is a way to run this in a debugger while writing the test, to extract, say, the number of expected call_counts for example.

Comment: you can print the call count out and then assert=False, then pytest will print it out, it prints stdout for failed tests.

Comment: .... The issue is that in order to get the call count I have to use mocker.spy which I cannot seem to run when debugging/developing, ONLY when running "pytest test_myunittests,py"

Comment: like I said, you run pytest while debugging, that's what I do anyway

Comment: You are right, I now understand what you mean. But that still doesn't allow me to set breakpoints etc.

Comment: you can set breakpoints actually also, for example just put `breakpoint()` in your file if you are python 3.7+ otherwise place `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` https://seleniumbase.com/the-ultimate-pytest-debugging-guide-2021/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. It still doesn't allow me to enter a method which has this format my_method(mocker) and thus, I am back at my initial problem: cannot debug tests which rely on "mocker"

Comment: you can set breakpoints within my_unittest and the "a_func", is that not enough? perhaps you could edit your question with what exactly you want to debug. You can also run pytest in debug mode, as is shown in the link I sent you, which means it breakpoints on every error.